# ListViewItem.Content only updates last item in ListView c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I have a program which works like a simple power point program. I am not working in a MVVM pattern.

I am saving all the slides that a user has created to an XML file and then reading this back in at a later date. My ListView which stores a preview of all slides currently created in the program when loaded only loads the ListView.Items.Content for the last slide in the list.

The following is the code I use to read the XML file.

```
private void Load()
        {
            List<SlideItems> listProjectContents = DeSerializeObjects();
            if (listProjectContents != null)
            {
                int loadCount = 0;
                foreach (SlideItems slide in listProjectContents)
                {
                    CreateNewSlide();
                    ListViewItem i = (ListViewItem)slideListView.Items[loadCount++];
                    BitmapSource bSource = Base64ToImage(slide.slidePreview);
                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.Source = bSource;
                    img.Height = 90;
                    img.Width = 190;
                    Border b = new Border();
                    StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
                    TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
                    t.Inlines.Add(loadCount.ToString());
                    s.Children.Add(t);
                    s.Children.Add(img);
                    b.Child = s;
                    i.Content = b;
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone see from this why only the ListView.Items.Content of the last ListView Item is displayed when I load from an XML file??

Answer (score 1):

This code is awful. Instead of trying to fix it, you should try to understand how things are done in wpf. Even if for some reason you are not using MVVM you can (and should) use data binding. In your case, you should

1) define a data template:

```
<ListView x:Name="slideListView">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <Image Width="190" Height="90" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

2) define item

```
class MyItem
{
    public BitmapSource Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

3) populate your `ListView` (should be done using MVVM instead, but oh well)

```
    private void Load()
    {
        slideListView.Items.Clear();
        List<SlideItems> listProjectContents = DeSerializeObjects();
        if (listProjectContents != null)
        {
            int loadCount = 0;
            foreach (SlideItems slide in listProjectContents)
            {
                BitmapSource bSource = Base64ToImage(slide.slidePreview);
                var item = new MyItem { Text = (loadCount++).ToString(), Image = bSource };
                slideListView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should include the <ListView /> node so OP can better understand binding - how you bind to the collection then specify the properties for different controls in template.

Comment: I have tried the code above but a string referring to the class is the only thing that is added to the listview using this code.

Comment: Hi, I did specify a data template in my xaml as show in in p.1

Comment: @kev3kev3, you would see a textbox + image then, not a class name.